# Find MLE for $\Phi, f(x;\Phi)=\frac{2x}{1-\Phi^{-1}}$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, log-likelihood

The probability distribution is given as

$$f(x;\Phi) = 
    \begin{cases}
       \frac{2x}{1-\Phi^{-1}}&  \Phi <x <1\\
       0& \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$$

How do I go about finding the MLE? Having difficulty with deriving the likelihood function

$$L(\Phi)= \frac{2x}{1-\Phi^{2}}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use Mathjax to render the math. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues ti clarify  ...

- $\Phi$ has a specific meaning in Statistics...better say $\theta$ for tour parameter
- You did not mention the parameter domain.... I checked it for you...  to have a noce density $\theta$ must be  $\in [0;1)$
- You did not mention the size of your random sample: let's say $n$

Now you can start.

Your model is not regular as the domain depends on $\theta$ so tour likelihood is

$L(\theta)\propto \frac {1}{(1-\theta^2)^n}\mathbb{1}_{[0;min(x))}(\theta)$

So it is strictly increasing and your MLE is

$\hat{\theta}= min(x)$